# Combining audio and video blob into a single blob to create background music to video?

Tags: javascript, blob, mediastream

Is there a way to combine audio blob and video blob into a single blob, thus creating a background music to the video? I tried doing something like this:

```
 var combined = [videoBlob, audioBlob];
 var newBlob = new Blob(combined);
```

But all it does is play the video animation, and then the sound. Is there a way to overlap both video and audio?

Comment: Sure, there are ways to mux audio and video together into a new container format, such as .mp4 or .mkv, and even do it with javascript. But that is needlessly complicated and processor-hungry for a web page. Why not just cue them to play() at the same time?

Comment: But are they still separated?

Comment: Yeah. If they have to be one blob for some reason, download and use a video editing program to put them together. Or upload it to YouTube or the like and use their video editing tools. Or use a tool like ffmpeg from the command line.

Comment: Actually putting a video stream and an audio stream into one container shouldn't really be processor-hungry, because you don't need to reencode the streams for that. If i use `ffmpeg` to do so, i always try to use copy mode for the streams, which makes the run almost be a simply copy. So should be absolutely doable in JavaScript. Depending on the input stream blobs, it could also be possible to prepare most of the container's headers and then just concat everything in the right order (probably depends on the container format). But that's a job, that takes more than one afternoon, I guess ;)

Comment: Were you able to find solution? I'm also having same problem where I'm trying to combine video and audio blobs together (`.webm` in my case) before downloading as a single video file.